# Unncessary pagebreak in the bibliography created by LaTex with the document class "ieeeconf"

Tags: bibliographies, page-breaking, ieeeconf

I am writing a paper in the template: `\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}`.
I am using these two command lines to insert my bibliography:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\bibliography{biblography}
```

The problem is that the bibliography is printed on half a page and the rest goes to the next page.

[image]

I have searched to find the solutions and tried to cover all similar questions here. None of them could solve my problem. Some answers were about increasing the `widowpenalty` or `clubpentalty`, but non of them worked.

I would be thankful if anyone can help.

here is the main.tex  I used

```
        \documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}  % Comment this line out if you need a4paper
    
    %\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, conference]{ieeeconf}      % Use this line for a4 paper
    
    \IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                              % This command is only needed if 
                                                              % you want to use the \thanks command
    
    \overrideIEEEmargins                                      % Needed to meet printer requirements.
    
    %In case you encounter the following error:
    %Error 1010 The PDF file may be corrupt (unable to open PDF file) OR
    %Error 1000 An error occurred while parsing a contents stream. Unable to analyze the PDF file.
    %This is a known problem with pdfLaTeX conversion filter. The file cannot be opened with acrobat reader
    %Please use one of the alternatives below to circumvent this error by uncommenting one or the other
    %\pdfobjcompresslevel=0
    %\pdfminorversion=4
    
    % See the \addtolength command later in the file to balance the column lengths
    % on the last page of the document
    
    % The following packages can be found on http:\\www.ctan.org
    %\usepackage{graphics} % for pdf, bitmapped graphics files
    %\usepackage{epsfig} % for postscript graphics files
    %\usepackage{mathptmx} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
    %\usepackage{times} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
    %\usepackage{amsmath} % assumes amsmath package installed
    %\usepackage{amssymb}  % assumes amsmath package installed
    \usepackage{bm}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
    \usepackage{fixltx2e}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    %\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{xparse}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{xmpmulti}
    \usepackage{transparent}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{cite}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    % the following packages can be found on http:\\www.ctan.org
    \usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,float}
    %\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode}
    %\usepackage[linesnumbered, algoruled, vlined]{algorithm2e}
    
    
    \usepackage[ruled, lined, linesnumbered, commentsnumbered, longend]{algorithm2e}
    
    
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{epsfig}
    \usepackage[all]{xy}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \usepackage{float}
    %\usepackage{txfonts}
    \usepackage{mathrsfs}  
    \usepackage{bm}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{color,soul}
    \usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,graphicx}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
    \usepackage{diagbox}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    %\usepackage[titletoc,toc,title]{appendix}
    \usepackage{units}
    \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
    
    
    %\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem} 
   
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-12cm}   % This command serves to balance the column lengths
                                  % on the last page of the document manually. It shortens
                                  % the textheight of the last page by a suitable amount.
                                  % This command does not take effect until the next page
                                  % so it should come on the page before the last. Make
                                  % sure that you do not shorten the textheight too much.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\section*{APPENDIX}

%Appendixes should appear before the acknowledgment.

%\section*{ACKNOWLEDGMENT}

%The preferred spelling of the word ÒacknowledgmentÓ in America is without an ÒeÓ after the ÒgÓ. Avoid the stilted expression, ÒOne of us (R. B. G.) thanks . . .Ó  Instead, try ÒR. B. G. thanksÓ. Put sponsor acknowledgments in the unnumbered footnote on the first page.



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%References are important to the reader; therefore, each citation must be complete and correct. If at all possible, references should be commonly available publications.



\titleformat{\section}{\centering\normalfont\scshape}{\appendixname~\thesection }{0em}{~}


\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\bibliography{biblography}




\end{document}
```

Here is the format of my `bibliography.bib`

```
@ARTICLE{Yan2019,

  author={Yan, Ruixuan and Xu, Zhe and Julius, Agung},

  journal={IEEE Robotics and Automation Letters}, 

  title={Swarm Signal Temporal Logic Inference for Swarm Behavior Analysis}, 

  year={2019},

  volume={4},

  number={3},

  pages={3021-3028},

  doi={10.1109/LRA.2019.2924843}}
  
@article{Rossa2020,
   author = {Della Rossa, Fabio and Salzano, Davide and Di Meglio, Anna and De Lellis, Francesco and Coraggio, Marco and Calabrese, Carmela and Guarino, Agostino Cardona-Rivera, Ricardo and De Lellis, Pietro and Liuzza, Davide and Lo Iudice, Francesco and Russo, Giovanni and di Bernardo, Mario},
   
   journal = {Nature Communications},
   
   month = {10},
   
   title = {A Network Model of Italy Shows That Intermittent Regional Strategies Can Alleviate the COVID-19 Epidemic},
   
   volume = {11},
   
   number = {5106},
   
   year = {2020},
   
   doi = {https://doi.org/10.1038/s41467-020-18827-5},
}

@article{Young2017,
   author = {Young, Joe and Young, Adam},
   
   journal = {Kaggle},
   
   month = {12},
   
   title = {Rain in Australia},
   
   year = {2017},
   
   url = {https://www.kaggle.com/jsphyg/weather-dataset-rattle-package},
}
```

Here are the IEEEtran.bst file
[Where I got the whole template](https://css.paperplaza.net/conferences/support/tex.php)

Sorry if the body of the question is long.

Comment: Can you create a minimal example which reproduces the problem, including a (short) bibliography file?  It's not like this is a common error ("Oh yeah!  I know how to fix that!")

Comment: @JohnKormylo I added more information. Do you think that is enough?

Comment: you have `\addtolength{\textheight}{-12cm}` -12cm !!! followed by a comment that says beware shortening the page too much.  Unrelated but you should remove any packages that you are not using, certainly epsfig and fixltx2e should not be used also you specify graphicx, float, bm (at least) twice.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you so much! it solved the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have

```
\addtolength{\textheight}{-12cm}
```

-12cm !!! followed by a comment that says beware shortening the page too much.

Simply delete this line.